# Taglib inheritance in jsp:include

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, taglib

Is it possible to inherit taglibs or imports from parent JSPs in their "descendants"?

Let me show you an example

`header.jsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" isELIgnored="false"
     import="org.something.utils.Constants"%>

//some code, Constants class is available here
```

`index.jsp`

```
<jsp:include page="template/header.jsp" />
//Constants is not available, I get a JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

also the taglibs inheritance doesn't seem to work. So is there a way how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taglibs and imports are not inherited, and everything in a tag as well cannot be inherited or passed through pages (except for JspContext and request attributes).

**You have two options here:**

1. Make the import in every JSP you have.
2. Make the common classes and libraries Global ones, this depends on the IDE and the server you are running.

**Edit**
Defining JSP implicit includes:

1. For Netbeans http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnajl/index.html
2. A global tutorial http://sabahmyrsh.blogspot.com/2009/06/jsp-defining-implicit-includes.html